What is the maximum area of n non-overlapping equal area triangles inscribed in a circle of radius
What is the maximum area of n non-overlapping equal area triangles inscribed in a circle of radius 1?
For n = 1, the triangle is equilateral.
For n = 2, we have 2 isosceles right triangles sharing a diameter (forming a square).
What about n = 3, 4... etc?

My guess is that for n>2, you inscribe an n-gon, and then subdivide from the center point to the vertices of the inscribed n-gon. For n=2 and n=1, your solutions seem right to me. I will try to give this more rigor tomorrow.

The equal area triangles must also be inscribed, so probably the subdivision of the n-gon must be done from one vertex, not from the center point.

I suspect (haven't yet proved it) that in an inscribed triangle, the area of the triangle will be greater than the area between the circle and its shortest side, so you cannot fit another triangle of the same area on that side. Thus to get $n$ triangles of equal area, they must form a sequence, with all but the two end triangles sharing a side with its predecessor and its sucessor. This can be accomplished by having a vertex common to all of them, but it can also be accomplished by occasionally switching the unshared sides from one hemi-circle to the other as one progresses along the sequence.

In any case, there will be $n+2$ edges on the outside of the polygon. Each interior triangle contributes a single exterior edge, while the two end triangles contribute $2$ exterior edges, so you need to inscribe an $n+2$ sided polygon to get $n$ inscribed triangles.

@PaulSinclair somehow missed that inscribed part in the question, haha. That certainly changes my thought process!

We can also calculate the case for n = 4. The maximum must be obtained by a symmetrical construction with two opposing right triangles sharing the diameter as a hypotenuse, while the outer catheti are the sides of two isosceles triangles. I am hoping that a pattern can emerge, but the case for (n = 3) is more complicated (one isosceles triangle in the middle with the main height along the diameter and two isosceles triangles on the sides).

The maximum area of an $n+2$ sided polygon occurs when the polygon is regular. The equal area requirement prevents all exterior sides from having the same length, but it is a sure bet that making them as close to equal as is possible will be the maximum.

Taking a fixed vertex in the north, the maximum size of an outer edge is on its left and right. The outer edge length decreases toward a minimum reached near the north-south diameter.
